# ngRepeat breaks the Foundation Switch CSS. How can I fix it?

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the [Switch](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html) component from Zurb's Foundation.

It works great until you put it inside an `ng-repeat`. Then, all the switches except the last one are broken--they don't display the labels until you click them.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uherim/8/edit) documenting the issue. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: They all seem to work for me in Chrome.

Comment: Just updated it with a new link that more clearly demonstrates the issue. You'll notice that the middle switches require a click before displaying the On/Off labels.

Comment: I would wrap that in a directive. To my mind its to many logic in the view. Additional values of id-attribute should not start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ng-model on your radios. It works fine in your JSBin if you include an ng-model on each radio button.

According to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio), value is also required.

Edit:

Okay look at [this version](http://jsbin.com/uherim/24/edit), I finally got it to work with both ng-model and ng-value, which I've learned is preferable to value. What do you think, does that work for you?

Apparently ng-repeat created a child scope for each iteration. Using $parent seems to be a way around that.

Comment: I tried that out [here](http://jsbin.com/uherim/18/edit) and it still is being screwy, specifically in that you must click the switch before it displays the "On" label. Compare the bottom three with the top one.

Comment: Try removing the "value" attribute. Strangely, it seems to work for me only if including ng-model and not including value, even though both are supposedly required...

Comment: Cool, it does indeed work! But if I can't use a value, how do I change the model based on the switch position?

Answer (score 0):

Found I had to use "ng-checked" in the following fashion for it to work as expected within an "ng-repeat". As long as the ng-clicked var is unique per switch, should work as expected. Make the toggle function something that toggles the visible value between true and false.

```
<div class="switch" ng-click="toggle()">
    <input type="radio" ng-checked="!visible">
    <label>Off</label>

    <input type="radio" ng-checked="visible">
    <label>On</label>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Hope that helps someone.